# Role based access control (RBAC) in Rails 4 + Emberjs application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ember.js, rbac

I am implementing role based access control in a Rails 4 app that uses Emberjs. I am planning to use Pundit in the rails code. Which plugins are available for Emberjs?. I am checking ember-simple-auth but can't understand https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#authorizers.

--update

I am using devise in rails for authentication and pundit for authorization. Authentication is working in Emberjs. My (rails+emberjs) app depends upon another rails app for data through api. Also, in my current app(rails+emberjs), the current_user(email and role_id) is stored only in session. There is no rails/emberjs model for user. I am using the env variables inside emberjs as

in app/assets/javascripts/app/env.js.coffee.erb

```
App.ENV =
  SOME_APP_URL: "<%= ENV['SOME_APP_URL'] %>"
```

can i use the above technique to load current_user from session?

Answer (score 1):

Simple-auth is to authenticate and authorize the api for a particular user. It does not deal with user authorizations. You have to deal with that yourself.

Once you dealt with authentication, I suggest you send the pundit authorizations to the client thru the user profile. I use a role based approach, but you can do it without that level.

So each role has pundit authorizations saved in db (I use PG arrays for this) in the form of ":" ("note:update", "note:create" for example). Roles are assigned to users and when the user model is serialized, so are the authorizations.

On the client side (and the backend, do not forget), you need to check those authorizations for each actions and routes.